# Desktop Background Group Policy - Windows XP, SBS 2008

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts, desktop, group-policy

I'm applying a desktop background via a group policy on user's PC's. It works fine on most, except for two PC's on which the desktop background is only applied to 1/5th of the background.
The rest of the background is just white.

I have tried pointing to the desktop background registry key to the item, and have also tried rebuilding the user's profile to no avail.

Comment: Is this a full screen background, or should it be tiled?

Comment: Hi, this is a full screen background.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working, just trying to get any information useful to someone that might know. a screenshot wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks so much for your input! Turns out I was given incorrect information and we hadn't actually rebuilt the offending profile. Profile rebuilld has resolved this issue!